# Looping through post request

Tags: python, request

I'm trying to create a loop in post request changing the environment of a application, but the script loops only on 'lab' environment, i'm using an restapi to send this requests and generate a different config files for each environment.

```
context="application-team"
clientToken="@option.clientToken@"

#Vars
vaultUrl="https://127.0.0.1:8200"

def createKvPath (vaultUrl):
    for environment in ['lab', 'stg', 'prod']:
        url = vaultUrl + '/v1/kv/'+context+'/application-name/'+environment+''
        payload = {'none':'none'}
        headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Vault-Token': clientToken,
            }
            resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
            dataKv = resp.json()

vault = createKvPath(vaultUrl)
```

Comment: How do you know that it loops only on 'lab' environment?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm sending requests to an restapi that generates a config file in different paths.

Comment: What is the output if you add `print('posting to', url)` above the line with `requests.post`?

Comment: The api returns <Response [204]>, that's only i got, checking the api, the only configuration i have created using this script is 'lab' env.

Comment: And what is the output of `print('posting to', url)` if you add it above the line `resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)`? How many "posting to ..." output lines do you get?

Comment: i got just only one result: {'posting to:' https://127.0.0.1/v1/kv/application-team/lab}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question removing `data Kv = resp.json()`, i don't know how `resp.json()` is locking the process.

```
def createKvPath (vaultUrl):
    for environment in ['lab', 'stg', 'prod']:
        url = vaultUrl + '/v1/kv/'+context+'/application-name/'+environment+''
        payload = {'none':'none'}
        headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Vault-Token': clientToken,
            }
            resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

vault = createKvPath(vaultUrl)
```